# 20newsgroup example Mahout local with no summary & confusion matrix, due to log4j warnings?

Tags: log4j, classification, mahout

Following the tutorial [here](http://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/twenty-newsgroups.html)
, everything seems working fine except that last test step did not display any summary or confusion matrix while in the folder I can see it has genereated files: ._SUCCESS.crc, .part-m-00000.crc,_SUCCESS & part-m-00000.

I got similar error like the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953397/how-to-resolve-log4j-warnings-while-executing-20newsgroup-classification-example) with no answers. Would be nice to know if it is due to log4g warnings? If yes(looks most likely),any detailed solution on how to solve this problem? Where exactly to add this properties file, how should it be look like etc.?

I am a new Mahout user, detailed info are highly appriciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    $ bin/mahout testnb -i /tmp/mahout-work/20news-test-vectors -m /tmp/mahout-work/model -l /tmp/mahout-work/labelindex -ow -o /tmp/mahout-work/20news-testing-result -c

    MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, so we don't add HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath.
    hadoop binary is not in PATH,HADOOP_HOME/bin,HADOOP_PREFIX/bin, running locally
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/mahout_src/examples/target/mahout-examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT-job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/mahout_src/examples/target/dependency/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Just found out the solution: create the property file [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261337/how-to-solve-log4jwarn-no-appenders-could-be-found-for-logger-error-on-twenty)

Comment: And put the file under mahout/src/conf(mahout has one log4j.properties under mahout/conf, which is not the right path and also the appender was not set correctly). Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.